# Rails: scope order question

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

I have some posts that belongs to location and category, sort of like craigslist post.

I want to order by most recently posted and also filter by location and category if those are specified by the user.

Can someone give an example/hints on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails 3 you can change together orders, wheres and more. ASCICasts on [activerecord queries in Rails3](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3)

```
query = Post.order("published_at desc")
query = query.where("location_id = ?", params[:location_id]) unless params[:location_id].blank?
query = query.where("category_id = ?", params[:category_id]) unless params[:category_id].blank?
@posts = query.all
```

Comment: how can I specify the location_id?

Comment: a post also has_many tags. For example, a post might have a java tag and a css tag.

I might want to filter all posts with just a java tag. Or posts with both java and css tag. How do I do that?

Comment: Line #2 of my code specifies the location_id. You should search or open a second question for how to do OR queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the field you would use to sort be category and location into the post.

```
before_save: cache_sortables

def cache_sortables
  self.category_title = self.category.title if self.category?
  self.location_title = self.location.title if self.location?
end

Post.find(:all, :order => 'location_title, category_title, created_at')
```

It is left as an exercise to the reader to update the posts when the parent category/location title changes.